# Ensure an argument is a compile time defined string literal

Tags: string, rust, sql-injection, string-literals

In order to prevent risk of SQL injection, I would like to create an API with a function that only accepts compile time string literals as an inputs e.g. `"SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;"`, `"WHERE price > 10"`, etc. The function can then do the required string concatenation, produce a `String` sql statment and execute it. This will be the only way to execute SQL so it guarantees that SQL statements are only created from bits of SQL defined by the developer, and any untrusted user input must be mapped to string literals. This removes any chance of user input ending up in a SQL statement. Is this possible?

Comment: Instead of allowing only compile-time strings, consider using placeholder values as a matter of habit, even if the data is compile-time. You'll still need to escape, and if you're doing this manually, that's bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take `&'static str`. This does not *completely* remove the risk, because of e.g. [`String::leak()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.leak) or unsafe code, but this makes it very unlikely.

If you really want, you can have a little macro:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct StringLiteral(&'static str);

impl StringLiteral {
    /// # Safety
    ///
    /// `v` must be a string literal.
    #[doc(hidden)]
    pub unsafe fn new(v: &'static str) -> Self {
        Self(v)
    }

    pub fn get(self) -> &'static str {
        self.0
    }
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! string_literal {
    ($v:literal) => {{
        let v = $v; // This has to be a separate statement, to not be in the `unsafe` block
        // SAFETY: We only accept literals.
        unsafe { $crate::StringLiteral::new(v) }
    }};
}
```

Then use `StringLiteral` everywhere in your code, which is impossible to construct (soundly) not from a literal.